# Strange chars while reading from file with fgetc

Tags: c, fgetc, non-unicode

When I printf the variable answer it contains several strange chars. What might be the reason?

```
int flag=0;
char answer[512];
char a[2];
a[1]='\0';

int c;
int status=1;
do {
      c = fgetc(pp);
      if( feof(pp) ) {
         break ;
        }
        if(c=='F' || status==0){
                a[0]=(char)c;
                strcat(answer,a);
                status=0;
        }
   } while(TRUE);
```

Comment: Perhaps the file contained strange chars

Comment: Set `answer[0]=0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strcat` expects the destination string to be valid - which means it must be null terminated. You are not explicitly null terminating the `answer` string. Add `answer[0]=0` before your loop.

Comment: @chux. I think the OP got `a[1]=0` correct. But missed `answer[0]=0`.

Comment: Yes, comment deleted.

Comment: thanks @MFisherKDX your suggestion was the fix. So even an empty string must be terminated with a 0?